# How to update the empty dataframe values with values from another dataframe(Pandas)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to update empty rows in dataframe1 with the equivalent values from dataframe2 only if the rows in dataframe1 is empty.

Cases:

[image: Dataframe1]

fig 1

[image: Dataframe2]

fig 2

In the above example, I want to fill only empty rows of Price columns in dataframe1 with the equivalent Price columns from dataframe2.

Any ideas or suggestions for this?

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('dataframe1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('dataframe2.csv')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 df2dict = df2.set_index(['Product Code'])['Price'].squeeze().to_dict()
 # maps from df2['Product Code'] to empty columns in df
 df['Price'] = df['Price'].fillna(df['Product Code'].map(df2dict))
```

Comment: I see that this post was edited, but shouldnt it be `df['Product Code'].map(df2dict)`? This will return a series that matches df1, but will only fill in the nan values.